# Rails Google Drive API (DriveV3) - service account - examples?

Tags: google-drive-api

Is there anyone who has a small WORKING example of how I can get rails to work with the Google Drive API (DriveV3).
I am really struggling ...

I have tried this code:

```
myauth = Google::Auth::ServiceAccountCredentials.make_creds(
  json_key_io: StringIO.new(File.read('config/autoakey.json')),
  scope: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
)
gsess = Google::Apis::DriveV3::DriveService.new
gsess.client_options.application_name = 'rails2'
gsess.authorization = myauth
gsess.authorization.fetch_access_token!

@google_docs = []

page_token = nil
begin
  (myfiles, page_token) = gsess.list_files(page_size: 10, q: "name contains ' '", fields: 'files(id, name), nextPageToken')
  myfiles.files.each do |file|
    @google_docs << file.name
  end
end while page_token
```

And initially I get no auth problem.
But the list_files does not return any files at all ...
Would you recommend that I integrate with Office365, S3 or something else instead?

With great hopes for a simple solution
Note: I am willing to skip DriveV3 if that can help.
Søren Rehné

Comment: It turns out that I read a lot regarding both the "console.google.xxx" site and that you need to remember to add the service account to the admin.google.com security page (under safety - go to administration of API-clientaccess). 
I had done this ... but here is MY clue that fixed everything:
Even though I had access to the domain. I still needed to add the service account email to the "share" menu of the folders I wanted to look into:
xxxxxxxxautomations.iam.gserviceaccount.com ... when I added this ... suddenly my list_files started to return files as expected. 
Stupid me ... ;-)

Comment: Hi Soren - i'm facing the same problem you faced. Where did you paste the above code and how did you call it? Moreover, do you have a code sample of getting your hello world ruby on rails app integrated with google drive?

Comment: I am REALLY buzy preparing a large release ... and I can't remember this issue (solution) ... but I looked at my files ... and perhaps this file can help you: It still works for me ;-) ...http://rehne.dk/posts/controller.rb

Comment: excellent thank you - there is another class the controller refers to: GoogleDrive::GoogleDocs.new - would you be able to paste that as well? I suspect it helps create/manage the service. - perhaps its in the /lib folder i don't know. if so that would be a mighty big help :) chrs

Comment: rehne.dk/posts/gdrivegdocs.rb